# Component undefined error when constructing object in function but not when manually entered into object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, importerror

My menu component uses list of objects with (list, edit, etc.) routes and attached components to decide where to navigate. I suspect I have some problem with import resolution.

First I was creating menu items using functions like this (one each for list, edit, etc. actions):

```js
// File: ./components/ListView/ListView.tsx

export function ListView(props: {
  apiViewSet: ApiViewset;
  tabViewSet: TabViewset;
}) {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

```js
// File: ./src/tabRouter.tsx

function createTestRouteManually() {
  return {
    element: () => ({
      content: (
        <ListView tabViewSet={tabViewset} apiViewSet={apiViewset} />
      ),
    }),
  };
}
```

Superflous fields were removed. This code worked well, since I had lots of routes using same generic ListView.

Then I needed to create some one-off routes with specific components, so I wrote more generic createRoute function:

```js
// File: ./src/tabRouter.tsx

function createRoute(content: ReactNode) {
  return { element: () => ({ content }) };
}

function createTestRoute() {
  return createRoute(
    <ListView tabViewSet={strojTabViewset} apiViewSet={strojApiViewset} />
  );
}
```

I expected that `createTestRoute` will work same as `createTestRouteManually`.

However when I tried `console.log(createTestRoute(), createTestRouteManually());` inside `./src/tabRouter.tsx` and reloaded the page, I got blank screen with error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ListView')
    at Module.ListView (createRouter.ts:68:1)
    at createTestRoute (tabRouter.tsx:39:1)
    at ./src/tabRouter.tsx (tabRouter.tsx:129:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/AppHeader/AppMenu/AppMenu.tsx (AppHeader.tsx:10:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

`npm start` shows no error in terminal. VSCode also doesn't notice anything wrong.

`./src/components/AppHeader/AppMenu/AppMenu.tsx` is first file which imports `./src/tabRouter.tsx`.

Problem doesn't occur when calling `createTestRouteManually();`, only when calling `createTestRoute();`.

First I tried to remove entire body of ListView, replacing it just with `return <div></div>;` like above. Error persists. Then I tried running `npm start` again, also didn't help.

Error only happens with components from subfolders of `components` folder.

My directory structure is:

```
src
- tabRouter.tsx
- components
- - AppHeader
- - - AppMenu
- - - - AppMenu.tsx
- - ListView
- - - ListView.tsx
- - - index.ts // Just: export * from "./ListView";
- - index.ts // Just: export * from "./ListView";
```

I get same error no matter if indexes are used or not. `import {ListView} from "./components";`, `import { ListView } from "./components/ListView";` and `import { ListView } from "./components/ListView/ListView";` all error. Renaming folder leads to same error, while creating new folder with same structure doesn't.

If I force syntax error by mistyping something and saving file while erroring site is open and then fix error, site reloads and works normally. If I enter erroring line while site is running also no error - but it errors on reload.

My question is of course, how to fix this - is this related to import resolution, what is likely reason?

---

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Project was created using `npx create-react-app --template typescript`.

- React version: 18.2.0
- Typescript version: 4.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I used `npx dpdm .\src\components\AppHeader\AppMenu\AppMenu.tsx` and found circular dependencies:

```
• Circular Dependencies
  1) src\components\AppHeader\AppMenu\AppMenu.tsx -> src\tabRouter.tsx -> src\components\index.ts -> src\components\AppHeader\index.ts -> src\components\AppHeader\AppHeader.tsx -> src\components\AppHeader\AppMenu\index.ts
  2) src\tabRouter.tsx -> src\components\index.ts -> src\components\ListView\index.ts -> src\components\ListView\ListView.tsx
```

After resolving them by changing all imports in `.\src\tabRouter.tsx` to point directly to files instead of to folders, application stopped erroring.